# Gmail Apps script function to list contents of All draft messages

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, gmail-addons

I'm looking for a Google Apps script for Gmail that would list the contents of the most recent draft message. So far my code is:

```
function listDrafts() {
  var drafts = Gmail.Users.Drafts.list('me')
  if (drafts.drafts.length == 0) {
    Logger.log('No draft messages found.');
  } else {
    Logger.log('Drafts:');
    for (var i = 0; i < drafts.drafts.length; i++) {
      var draft = drafts.drafts[i].message.payload.headers[i].value;
      Logger.log('- %s', draft);
    }
  }
}
```

However, I keep getting an error on run. Appreciate any help.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your script, when Gmail API is enabled at Advanced Google services, I thought that an error might occur at the line of `var draft = drafts.drafts[i].message.payload.headers[i].value;`, because `drafts.drafts[i].message.payload` returns `undefined`. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, how about the following modification?

From:

```
var draft = drafts.drafts[i].message.payload.headers[i].value;
```

To:

```
var draft = Gmail.Users.Drafts.get("me", drafts.drafts[i].id).message.payload.headers[i].value;
```

or

To:

```
var headers = Gmail.Users.Drafts.get("me", drafts.drafts[i].id).message.payload.headers;
for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
  Logger.log(headers[j].value)
}
```

#### Note:

- [When you use this script, please enable Gmail API at Advanced Google services.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)

#### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Users.drafts: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/list)
- [Users.drafts: get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/get)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Edit:

- You want to retrieve the email from the headers of `Gmail.Users.Drafts`.

For this situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var draft = drafts.drafts[i].message.payload.headers[i].value;
```

To:

```
var headers = Gmail.Users.Drafts.get("me", drafts.drafts[i].id).message.payload.headers;
for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
  var search = ["From", "To"];
  if (search.indexOf(headers[j].name) != -1) {
    Logger.log(headers[j].value)
  }
}
```

- If you want to retrieve the values except for "From" and "To", please modify `var search = ["From", "To"];`

Comment: Hi there Tanaike - Thanks so much for your response. Your modification does seem to return a value now, however it seems that I was looking for the email addresses specified in the header, but it's only returning the value "1.0" -- any insights on that?

Comment: @Sherif Kamal-ElDin Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I have to apologize again.

Comment: Hi Tanaike -- You, my friend are the real MVP! it's now working perfectly as intended. Thanks a lot sir!

Comment: @Sherif Kamal-ElDin Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.